# Why is it not possible to overload insertion operators in c++ for a dynamic array?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, friend

I'm new to C++. Just out of curiosity, I'm trying to see what happens when I try to overload the insertion ">>" operator for a class of dynamic array. I think what I'm trying to do is impossible. But could anyone explain what this error means? (error below the code)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class Type>
class Array{
    private:
    int length;
    Type* ptrarr;

    public:
        int size() const;
        Type* get_array() const;
        friend istream& operator >> (istream& s, Array<Type>& arr);

};

template<class Type>
int Array<Type>::size() const{
    return length;
}

template<class Type>
Type* Array<Type>::get_array() const{
    return ptrarr;
}

template<class Type>
istream& operator >> (istream& s, Array<Type>& arr){
    cout << "Enter length of array"; cin >> arr.length;
    arr.ptrarr = new Type[arr.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        cout << "Array[" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> *(arr.ptrarr + i);
    }
    return s;
}


int main(){
    Array<int> intarray;
    cin >> intarray;
    int* ptr = intarray.get_array();
    for(int i =0; i < intarray.size(); i++)
        cout << *(ptr+i);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error

```
in function `main':
dyn_array.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `operator>>(std::istream&, Array<int>&)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but a stream extractor shouldn’t prompt for input. That prompt will be very confusing when the program reads from a file.

Comment: It should also use the stream given to it instead of hardcoding `cin`. The idea is that you write one overload to support input and it works with any input source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `friend` declaration refers to a non-template `operator>>`, which doesn't match the definition of the template one.

Make the `friend` declaration refering to the template `operator>>`, e.g.

```
// forward declaration for the class template
template<class Type>
class Array;
// declaration
template<class Type>
istream& operator >> (istream& s, Array<Type>& arr);
```

then

```
template<class Type>
class Array{
    // friend declaration
    friend istream& operator >> <Type> (istream& s, Array<Type>& arr);
    //                          ^^^^^^
    //                  or just <> (make use of template argument deduction)
    ...
};

// definition
template<class Type>
istream& operator >> (istream& s, Array<Type>& arr) {
    ...
}
```

Or as [Remy Lebeau commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66978577/why-is-it-not-possible-to-overload-insertion-operators-in-c-for-a-dynamic-arra/66978599?noredirect=1#comment118395925_66978599), keep `operator >>` as non-template, and define it in the class definition.

```
template<class Type>
class Array{
    ...
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& s, Array<Type>& arr) {
        ...
    }
};
```